# Remove Admin Notice on page refresh

Tags: wp-list-table, notices

I have a simple question about admin notices. I want to display a message like 'Record updated successfully', and when user refresh again same page, then this notice should not be there as no record is updated again.

Just like settings Api, there is notice as 'Settings saved.' and when we refresh the page the notice is not there. I see in URI argument is there as

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=xyz&settings-updated=true
```

I know here **settings-updated=true** is the key, and it disappear immediately and user can hardly notice it. But I don't know how it disappears after taking effect. I think I am missing very simple and basic trick.

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by [wp_admin_canonical_url](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.1.1/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L1150):

- It calls [wp_removable_query_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_removable_query_args/) to fetch a list of query string parameters to remove, which includes `settings-updated`.
- It then writes some script into the page header to use `window.history.replaceState` to remove the query string from your browser's URL bar.

  ```
  <link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical"
        href="http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=xyz">
  <script>
      if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
          window.history.replaceState( null, null,
              document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href +
                  window.location.hash );
      }
  </script>
  ```

If you want to add your own arguments to the list that gets removed then you can hook [removable_query_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/removable_query_args/).